# I need a guidance or correction for my codings mobile express checkout payment in paypal using php?

Tags: php, mobile, paypal, checkout

The Following codings does not working for me.,The amount doesn't paid to relevant merchant id's i provided.,any mistakes are happen on my codings.,Is any body well known in this means i need help for this ASAP...

```
$nvpstr.="&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=http://project.websolusionz.com/paypal/demo/thanks.php
&CANCELURL=http://project.websolusionz.com/paypal/demo/cart.php
&PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=0.1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=0.1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=My Product (Product1)
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=merch1_1305546355_biz@gmail.com
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART26488-PAYMENT0
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=My Product (Product 1)
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=0.1

&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=0.1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=0.1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC1=My Product (Product 5)
&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=merch2_1305546449_biz@gmail.com
&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART26488-PAYMENT1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME1=My Product (Product 5)
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY1=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT1=0.1";
```

**My PayPal URL And End Point :**

```
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";

$PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&useraction=commit&token=";
```

Mobile View is not working correctly And one more thing i want to set up the 5% commission to the main dealer.,Is this possible in mobile express checkout...?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Change your endpoint to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp and your redirect URL to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=XXXX - you're currently using Sandbox accounts (merch1_xxxxxxxxxxxx_biz@gmail.com) on the Live endpoint and redirecting to the Live URL.

You'll need to use the API credentials of your Sandbox seller account against the Sandbox NVP endpoint (shown above). The API call itself looks fine at first glance.

Comment: $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
$PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&useraction=commit&token=";

Already i placed a End point and PayPal Url it couldn't work for me...

Comment: i didn't get any error messages but the amount will not increase or decrease i mean debit or credit on any of the given accounts..(merchant id's)